# How can I find the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to determine the subgroup lattice for $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$.

The order of all subgroups divides the order the group.

So, since $|\mathbb{Z}_{20}|=20$, the orders of the subgroups are: $20,10,5,4,2,1$.

But how can I find these subgroups??

Comment: If $\gcd(n,m)=1$ then $\Bbb Z_{nm}\simeq\Bbb Z_n\times \Bbb Z_m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that if $C_n = \{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{n-1} \}$ is a cyclic group generated by $x$, then every subgroup of $C_n$ has the form $\langle x^d \rangle$ for some $d$ dividing $n$.  Thus, $C_{20}$ has exactly six subgroups:  $\langle x^d \rangle$ for $d=1,2,4,5,10,20$.  The lattice should be clear.

Comment: So, since the group $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ has the operation $"+"$, the generator is $<[1]>$, right? So, are the subgroups the following??
$$<1 \cdot [1]>=<[1]>, \ \ <2 \cdot [1]>=<[2]>, \ \ <4 \cdot [1]>=<[4]>, \ \ <5 \cdot [1]>=<[5]>, \\ <10 \cdot [1]>=<[10]>, \ \ <20 \cdot [1]>=<[20]>$$

Comment: @MaryStar that is correct.

Comment: And the order of each subgroup is as followed:
$$ord(<[1]>)=20, \ \ ord(<[2]>)=10, \ \ ord(<[4]>)=5, \ \ ord(<[5]>)=4, \ \ ord(<[10]>)=2, \ \ ord(<[20]>=<[0]>)=1$$ Is this correct??

Comment: @MaryStar yes, it is.

Comment: Great!!! Thanks a lot!!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Consider the canonical projection $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_{20}$ and use the isomorphism theorem that relates the subgroups of the image with the subgroups that contain the kernel.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Which one of the three isomorphism theorems is that one?